# how to Execute .aspx file on server

Tags: asp.net, apache, web, vs-web-site-project, website-hosting

Sir,
I have designed a website using Visual Studio using asp.net, it is successfully getting executed on localhost
I want to make the website live on my own server.
After uploading the project files on server and then checking on the link www.abc.com/project
it gives the following error:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /project/ on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at abc.com Port 80

Note: the host is linux based server, and the website project is not having a database

Comment: Is that **Linux** server able to process **Microsoft** ASP.Net files? Usually you deploy ASP.Net to a Windows server.

Comment: Not usually, only. You cannot run ASP.NET on Linux.

Comment: I think you can run asp.net on linux using grasshopper...

Comment: Using a platform to compile .NET code into Java is not the same as running .NET on LINUX, which again, you cannot do.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You added to your question that the host is a Linux server running Apache. You cannot run an ASP.NET application on Linux/Apache.

Prev: I'm leaving the information below for other people who might search for this problem when running IIS.

Locate the folder's physical location on the hard drive and pull up the Security settings. Depending on what operating system you are using, make sure the following have read/execute privileges (write as well depending on the functions of the site):

- IIS_IUSRS
- IUSR_MACHNAME
- NETWORK
- NETWORK SERVICE

If you still have problems, open the Web.config (or machine.config) and add

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

in the System.Web node.

Comment: Note: those are Windows users, and the OP is deploying to Linux/Apache!

Comment: The original post said nothing about linux/apache, which I'm not sure how anybody who has ever used Microsoft .NET would assume that the .NET framework would magically work on Linux.